# Unity, GameObject Sprite(2D) how to remove transparent part?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I had join few pieces image to be a Map, and i make it able to click also.
but the problem is the image itself had transparent part, so when i click "Section A", maybe will trigger "Section B". Because "Section B" had transparent part is overlap on the Section A area.

So my question is, is that possible had any properties can adjust like it will auto remove transparent part?

or is must manual to adjust the Collider area? because my images had a lot, if manual adjust one by one, then is really take a lot of time.

And i using Box Collider for additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1. Pick some layered sprites. Access the texture of each sprite and read pixel from it,  providing coordinates sophisticatedly extracted from mouse position, sprite position on screen and texture bounds provided by sprite. Supposing that opaque parts of sprites are not intersected, any sprite that have opaque pixel at given coordinates will be the result of picking.

Option 2. Replace box colliders with procedurally generated mesh colliders. The procedure will receive the same texture of sprite as an input and generate outline(s) using, say, marching squares algorithm. To convert outline vertices into mesh the procedure may use any trianulation algorithm that works well with concave polygons.